# R: exporting R data to Stata with variable labels

Tags: r

I tried to export my R data to Stata with variable names and variable labels. I can see that my r data have both variable names and labels when using describe(data), but when I export it, stata data file has only variable name.

could you let me know how attribute is stored as label? @shreyasgm

my codes are

`# my data`

```
`county`
```

`# Add variable labels -----------------------------------------------------`

```
`county_layout %>%
   select(field, var_label) %>%
    deframe() %>%
    as.list() -> var_label(county)
var_label(county)`

`write.dta(county, "county.dta",convert.factor="labels")`
```

Comment: Does this not work even with `write_dta` from `haven`? I think the attribute would have to be stored as `label`.

Comment: Provide a reproducible example